IP rights when a contracted PhD or research fellow makes accidental/incidental discovery
This question arises from a matter raised on SE Academia.
It clearly has strictly legal as well as academic aspects. So I will raise it here.
Basically a PhD or research fellow has a university research contract to explore field X. He/She is performing this work with satisfactory progress for say a year when a discovery is made that doesn't pertain to the objects of the research program. However this discovery offers clear progress in field Y - either through its inherent scientific insight, its commercial applications or its importance in national defence.
Under a standard PhD or fellowship researcher's contract, all discoveries derived from the research program are the intellectual property of either the university and/or the program sponsor, e.g. a research foundation or private corporation. Sometimes there is a sunset clause on this IP claim, e.g. up to 18 months after the end date of the program.
But the latter provision does not anticipate accidental discoveries in other fields, moreover ones that are purely serendipitous, i.e. they could have been made under other circumstances by the researcher without the library or laboratory facilities used during the research program. Neither does the analytical expertise acquired during the postgraduate research contribute to the recognition of the discovery's scientific or industrial potential - this is entirely the researcher's own insight.
We all know that if the researcher shared knowledge of this discovery with their program supervisor, it's likely that the university or program sponsor would claim IP rights on it. Obviously, the legal might of a university with its own law faculty's free expertise and, more to the point, its ability to attract the cut-rate support of big law firms hoping to capture that university (and hence others) as a client, strongly deters a legal challenge by the researcher.
But, from a strictly legal perspective and given the circumstances and the very specious input, if any at all, by the university or program sponsor into this discovery, doesn't the researcher have a good case to be assigned the major share of the IP rights from this discovery ?
EDIT
This Oxford case explores the issues involved.

Researchers are paid to use their brains, and if, in the course of performing some work on project X you come up with something about Y, well, you are being paid to use your brain and your brain came up with Y (which somehow magically has no relationship whatsoever to X?). All IP questions will be answered between specific contract/grant terms and your employment contract. I know full well that my company owns anything technical unless they choose to pass on it (which does happen).

I don't know of any contract which would give the university ownership of the researcher's work only on the condition that the idea is within field X. Why would the contract specify this? It seems only to invite unnecessary arguments about what is or isn't within the field of X, and make it harder for the researcher to transfer a different team (by requiring a new contract to be drawn up in that case).

Or a good answer could address all the questions raised here in comments...

You're spending a lot of attention on irrelevant details. Let's put those aside first.
The "discovery" has to be patentable; the "Intellectual Property" would have to be a patent. Copyrighted works and trademarks are not "discovered".
It is entirely irrelevant how much progress the PhD candidate made, or how satisfactory this is. Patent law does not care.
Patent law does require that the invention is non-obvious, even to people skilled in the field (i.e. those familiar with field "Y"). But again, patent law does not are that the inventor worked in field X originally.
Patent law does care about IP assignment in contracts. If the contract says that the patent rights are assigned to the university, then that holds. If the contract says they're assigned to the sponsor, then that holds. If the contract says that they're assigned to the researcher, then that holds. As your "sunset clause" shows, this can depend on the facts at hand.
Now that we've established what the law says, and what the contract could say, we're only left with the actual facts. The sole differentiating fact here is that the discovery is in a field Y, not a field X. This is materially irrelevant to the contract as that does not mention specific fields.
Hence, based on the facts, contract and law, the patent goes to the university or sponsor.

That's the IP law take - refer to the employment contract. And this will hold as long as the contract terms are reasonable and fair. I can hire Ms Z as a barmaid but can't insist that she go topless every Saturday night to boost sales. The notion that everything patentable seen and reported by an employee within an employment contract belongs to the assignee named in the contract would (a) discourage keen observation and/or (b) encourage concealment of incidental discoveries.

@Trunk (legal interpretation X) would (lead to bad things) Maybe, but so what? It does not make the interpretation incorrect.

@Trunk The reason you can't make that contract with Ms. Z is because of sex work laws; it has nothing to do with "reasonable and fair". With specific exceptions, contract terms are presumed to be "reasonable and fair"; otherwise, the parties wouldn't have agreed to them. And a contractual stipulation that all discoveries belong to a particular party, rather than more vague and complex terms, is not in the same zip code as "unreasonable".

I think that there are law on indecency too that would void it.

My point is that IP rights assignment to a university or program sponsor is rationally based on the fact that they provide facilities and/or salary for the duration of the program. Were any discovery to involve use of university facilities or training acquired during the program the naturally the university or sponsor would have a strong claim. But where it's simply an observation and a thought process done by the researcher - which could have been done elsewhere in many other circumstances - then how can the university or sponsor make a claim on the IP involved here ?

@Trunk Because that's the contract the researcher and the university entered into. Having a simple term like that avoids the sort of impossibly subjective wrangling over "was it done elsewhere" that could otherwise arise, but the fundamental reason the university could make a claim is that's what the two of them decided on.

@Sneftel  Just because a PhD/fellow signs a contract with such IP assignments doesn't mean that that agreement becomes reasonable and fair. The signee may be in a very poor bargaining position and the eventualities referred to very rarely occur anyhow: at that point PhD/fellow just wants to do a research job. Please read the Oxford case for the judge's comments on excessive range of uni's claim vs those of other unis and the clear imbalance in power between the uni and researcher.

You have not provided sufficient facts on which an analysis can be based.
You have only said what a "standard" contract contains, but not what this hypothetical researcher's contract contains. Even though there is obviously variation from institution to institution, you get to stipulate the facts that you want us to analyze. You get to create the terms of the contract for our analysis, but you haven't.
You have said the standard contract does not anticipate discoveries in other fields, but what matters is not what is anticipated, but what the meaning of the provision actually encompasses.
You have said there may or may not be input from the university, and if there is, that you have classified it as specious (without providing facts by which we could confirm this classification — a classification that is of dubious relevance in any case).
Without knowing what the actual terms of this hypothetical contract, or what the hypothetical input from the university is, or whether there was even input from the university, no legal analysis can be applied to the scenario you have attempted to describe.
However, the background principles are as follows:

who is an inventor or co-inventor is a question of fact that depends heavily on the actual inputs provided from those potential co-inventors
whether a researcher's inventions must be assigned in whole or part to the university is a question of contract law and the precise terms of any contract


Every university/foundation/corporation has its own contract. We do not know if any given university makes provision for this very rare eventuality. A small few may claim to do so. Others say nothing. Even if they did, how could they prevail with their IP rights claims simply by "covering" this eventuality in the contract ? Contract terms must be fair and reasonable. And a university gaining $x million a year in royalties/research grants from a discovery made by a PhD gaining nothing bar his name on the patent or on the seminal paper resulting from it would be both unfair and unreasonable.
